# How to write units raised to some number in titles of axes in an IDL plot window?

Tags: idl-programming-language

The titles of axes in a plot usually consists of units of some physical parameter. How do we represent such a unit, especially when it contains some letter raised to the power some number?
For example, if the x-axis represents velocity, how can we represent m s^-1 properly as the xtitle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the graphics system you are using.

If you are using function graphics, then you can do something like:

```
IDL> p = plot(/test, ytitle='velocity $m s^{-1}$')
```

If you are using direct graphics, then do:

```
IDL> plot, findgen(10), ytitle='velocity m s!E-1!N'
```

See the [Doc Center](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Embedded_Formatting_Comm.html) for a complete listing of the embedded graphics format codes.

There are also helpful library routines to help with direct graphics.

Comment: Thanks @mgalloy, that worked. Could you please give the links for the relevant documents so that I can refer them for more complicated needs in the future.

Comment: Updated my answer with the link. Glad that was useful!